# Baby Cry Sound detection

Tags: audio, fft

I wanted to write a code to detect baby cry sound. I am using Windows as platform. Presently, I am able to get audio samples and its frequency plot(using FFT) but not sure how to proceed forward.

I wanted to ask what steps I should follow to detect the baby cry sound given its time-frequency plot.

I saw some methods such as median filter followed by HMM in speech recognition. But for simple sound detection do I need to go for such sophiticated method?

I will be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more about DSP theory than actual programming - it *would* be on-topic however on http://DSP.stackexchange.com

Comment: I had posted there, but didn't receive any response. Also there are many related questions posted over here with tags'sound'.

Comment: You only posted the question on DSP.SE **2 hours ago** - expect to wait at least 24 hours (more on a weekend), for good answers. Please also read the online [help] for both sites to understand what's on-topic - you can ask questions about sound and signal processing here if they have a programming aspect (i.e. code), but for theory questions such as this you'll get a better response on DSP.SE (if you're patient!).

Comment: Hi! did you work with baby cry detection? if you done please guide me?

Comment: Sorry, i didnt complete this project.

Answer (score 4):

Hidden markov models are widely used in speach recognition, but since you don't really need to know what your baby is saying (next project: baby translator), i don't think it is what you need.

What you should probably do is look at a lot of spectorgrams of babies crying, and look for patterns. Or, even better, let your algorithm do this. What you do is calculate certain metrics about your sound called [MFCCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum).
You do this on, say, 1000 samples of crying sound, and then you have a 1000 vectors of metrics.

Now, for each metric you calculate the standard deviation. This gives you a way to tell of a sample of random babysound how much different it is from *avarage crying sound*.

This sounds very hard, but i know there are tools out there. Have a look at sphinx. You can probably train to work.

But either way, start by collecting baby-crying sounds ;) (but don't steal candy)

Comment: hi! #David van rijn hope you are doing well! I recently got to start working with same idea, to monitor baby cry, laugh etc can you please suggest some lib if available in java or android or some helpful guidens?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know any libraries in java, since i never use it. I only know sphinx. There is also [pocketsphinx](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx), and they say they have android support. But i have no experience with this.